# How to create csv file after xml parsing using python

Tags: python, xml, csv

I'm pretty new on python, I have been able to parse my xml file and to get what I expected, here is a bit of the output I got on my shell :

```
 * p84182 [Goalkeeper] 16 - total_through_ball = [1]
 * p84182 [Goalkeeper] 16 - duel_lost = [4]
 * p84182 [Goalkeeper] 16 - blocked_scoring_att = [1]
 * p84182 [Goalkeeper] 16 - leftside_pass = [46]
 * p84182 [Goalkeeper] 16 - dispossessed = [1]
 * p84182 [Goalkeeper] 16 - accurate_cross = [2]
 * p84182 [Goalkeeper] 16 - att_rf_total = [1]
```

I would like to convert that on a csv file with this 5 columns, but I get the same error everytime I run my code :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hp\Documents\test4.py", line 20, in <module>
    print.fichier(ID,Position,Shirt,Types,Reponse)
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'fichier'
```

Here is my python code :

```
import os
from xml.etree import ElementTree
import csv

file_name="C:/Users/Hp/Desktop/BYG/PSG-Amiens.xml"
full_file=os.path.abspath(os.path.join('BYG',file_name))
dom=ElementTree.parse(full_file)

fichier=open('data.csv','w')

Stats=dom.findall('SoccerDocument/MatchData/TeamData/PlayerLineUp/MatchPlayer')

Type=dom.findall('SoccerDocument/MatchData/TeamData/PlayerLineUp/MatchPlayer[@PlayerRef="p15780"]/Stat')
for s in Stats:
    ID=s.get('PlayerRef')
    Position=s.get('Position')
    Shirt=s.get('ShirtNumber')
    for t in Type:
            Types=t.get('Type')
            Reponse=t.text
            print.fichier(ID,Position,Shirt,Types,Reponse)

fichier.close()
```

How to fix that? and convert my xml parsing to a csvfile?

Comment: is it not : print.fichier that throws your error?

Comment: This is why you **always** must supply the entire traceback in your question. It gives **far more** information than just the literal Error text.

Comment: @MatinaG thanks for the answers, I updated my question, and yes it's print.fichier that throws your error

Answer (score 0):

`print.fichier` isn't valid.  To print to a file use `print(ID,Position,Shirt,Types,Response,file=fichier)`, but that won't give you a `.csv` either.  See the `csv` module.  The basics of writing a CSV are:

```
import csv
with open('data.csv','w',newline='') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow([ID,Position,Shirt,Types,Response])
```